# Print key and if conditional is met print key value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I would like to create simple "coding script".

I have this dictionary:

```
diction =  {
"A" :  "Z", 
"Y" :  "B",
"C" :  "X"
}
```

I want to give some random sentence, iterate through it's letters and if letter is found in this dictionary - print opposite letter
So, If I put word

`"ABC"`

it should return:

`"ZYX"`

I tried this code, but I have a "KeyError"  :

```
# Defining dictionary
diction =  {
"A" :  "Z", 
"Y" :  "B",
"C" :  "X",
"W" :  "E",
"E" :  "V",
"U" :  "F",
"G" :  "T",
"S" :  "H",
"I" :  "R",
"Q" :  "J",
"K" :  "P",
"O" :  "L",
"M" :  "N",
" " :  " "
}

# Sentence in "szyfr" variable should be split into list.

szyfr = "SOME SENTENCE WHATEVER"

def split(szyfr): 
     return [char for char in szyfr]

szyfr = split(szyfr)


# Now I want to iterate through "szyfr" and replace letters as in "CAT" example:  

for i in szyfr:
        if i in diction:
                
                diction = {x:y for x,y in diction.items()}
                print(i)
                print("Variable: " + i + " is in 'key'")
                pass
        elif diction[i] in szyfr:
                diction = {y:x for x,y in diction.items()}
                print(i)
                print("Variable: " + i + " is in 'value'")
        elif i is " ":
                pass

print(szyfr)
```

Comment: Why in your loop are you altering `diction`?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some letters, such as `N`. Note that `{"M": "N"}` is not the same thing as `{"N": "M"}`.

That being said, you don't even need a dictionary as if you subtract the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of an uppercase letter (such as 65 for A) from 155 (65+65+26-1) you will end up with the ASCII code of the corresponding letter:

```
>>> szyfr = "SOME SENTENCE WHATEVER"
>>> "".join(chr(155-ord(e)) if "A" <= e <= "Z" else e for e in szyfr)
'HLNV HVMGVMXV DSZGVEVI'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use a dict in which for each key 'letter' has the value 'opposite letter' :

This is a possible solution :

```
diction = {" ": " "}

all_letters = range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)
for char, opsite_char in zip(all_letters, reversed(all_letters)):
    diction[chr(char)] = chr(opsite_char)

print(diction)
```

**OUTPUTS :**

```
{' ': ' ', 'A': 'Z', 'B': 'Y', 'C': 'X', 'D': 'W', 'E': 'V', 'F': 'U', 'G': 'T', 
'H': 'S', 'I': 'R', 'J': 'Q', 'K': 'P', 'L': 'O', 'M': 'N', 'N': 'M', 'O': 'L', 
'P': 'K', 'Q': 'J', 'R': 'I', 'S': 'H', 'T': 'G', 'U': 'F', 'V': 'E', 'W': 'D', 
'X': 'C', 'Y': 'B', 'Z': 'A'}
```

Comment: Easier method: `import string; d = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, reversed(string.ascii_uppercase)))`

Comment: True, but I thought by showing the relationship between their ASCII, it might help  him realize that the question doesn't even need the creating of a dict.In case the problem doesn't demand it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the code you gave, I find the following oddities:

```
szyfr = "SOME SENTENCE WHATEVER"

def split(szyfr): 
     return [char for char in szyfr]

szyfr = split(szyfr)
```

It seems you're trying to build a list from a character string, which can be simply done as:

```
>>> s = "hola"
>>> l1 = list(s)
>>> l1
['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']
```

So, in your specific case:

```
szyfr = "SOME SENTENCE WHATEVER"
szyfr = list(szyfr)
```

Though, it is not really needed, since you can directly manage a string as if it were a list, with a **for**.

Now, you want to replace the chars following an specific dictionary. I find your solution too complex, while you only need:

```
diction =  {
"A" :  "Z", 
"Y" :  "B",
"C" :  "X",
"W" :  "E",
"E" :  "V",
"U" :  "F",
"G" :  "T",
"S" :  "H",
"I" :  "R",
"Q" :  "J",
"K" :  "P",
"O" :  "L",
"M" :  "N",
" " :  " "
}

sentence_to_code = input("Give me a sentence: ").strip().upper()
toret = ""

for ch in sentence_to_code:
    coded_ch = diction.get(ch)

    if not coded_ch:
        coded_ch = ch

    toret += coded_ch

print(toret)
```

If you are not defining correspondents to all possible characters, then it is sensible to use the *get(k)* method of the dictionary, which returns **None** when the key *k* is not found.

It must be taken into account that the *get(k)* method has default parameter for the return value in case the key is not found, so you can use *get(k, default_return_value)*, which lets us simplify the code even more:

```
diction =  {
"A" :  "Z", 
"Y" :  "B",
"C" :  "X",
"W" :  "E",
"E" :  "V",
"U" :  "F",
"G" :  "T",
"S" :  "H",
"I" :  "R",
"Q" :  "J",
"K" :  "P",
"O" :  "L",
"M" :  "N",
" " :  " "
}

sentence_to_code = input("Give me a sentence: ").strip().upper()
toret = "".join([diction.get(ch, ch) for ch in sentence_to_code])

print(toret)
```

Now we are using a list comprehension, since we don't need a conditional any more. The call `diction.get(ch, ch)` returns *ch* or the corresponding coded char, or *ch* itself if it is not found in the dictionary. With the call to [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join), i.e., `"".join(...)` we transform the list back in a string.